# mat-slider not updating textbox as moved

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want mat-slider to update textbox as user using it real time. Currently only after user done dragging it with mouse the event is fired and it is being updated. When using keyboard it works as expected. How can I achieve same behavior when mouse used? I tried using change, input and ngModelChange events and none of those works as expected.

Sample app [here](https://angular-hhu9qq.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this:

```
(input)="inputUpdate($event)"
```

to your html component

and on your ts class add the inputUpdate function:

```
inputUpdate(matSliderChange:any) {
    this.value = matSliderChange.value;
  }
```

you can change the any type that i used with the real type "MatSliderChange".